# How can I delete rows in a database using a query?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

There is a user with the attribute `Role`, by default `TENANT`, using a query we set him `LANDLORD` and in the`HOUSE` table he adds an apartment with various attributes: description, price, city_id and others. But suddenly this user wanted to remove himself from the status of `LANDLORD`, delete his apartments from our database and again become just`TENANT`, how in this case can I delete the information that he has apartments? How to do it, if he has apartments, then they need to be deleted, if not, then just change the user's status to `TENANT`?

At first there was an idea to assign a zero value, but it seemed strange to me if we just zeroed it out, because then the table will start to get cluttered. There is also a status option: `ACTIVE` or `BANNED`, but I don't like this option, because his apartment is still not needed.

The code looks like this:

```java
@PutMapping ("/ {id}")
@PreAuthorize ("hasAuthority ('landlord: write')")
public void TenantPostAdd (@PathVariable (value = "id") Long id) {
    User user = userRepository.findById (id) .orElseThrow ();
    Role role = Role.TENANT;
    user.setRole (role);
    House house = houseRepository.findById (id) .orElseThrow ();
    house ... // what's here
}
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build this level of infrastructure, there are a lot of questions I would have to ask to recommend something. I'd want to see the current database schema as well. Your also requesting the ability to delete which can become problematic. You may want to consider leaving data if you believe that the customer may change roles again. That kind of information is based off of the terms of agreement.

Have you considered building something like this?

Absolute(Numeric)          Mode

0   No Permission           --- etc...

https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html

This could be a prepared statement issue with not the appropriate joins occurring in the statement. I believe you should take another look over your database schema.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There is no need to delete anything, I entered the "status" attribute in house, so now if there is no owner, I make it inactive.